# How set custom url for storage in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I want use laravel storage in my project. this is my structure in filesystem:

```
'public' => [
         'driver' => 'local',
         'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
         'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/images',
         'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

But this url always give me 404 error;
I try

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

But nothing change and only default 'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage' works.
Whats wrong with that? How I can change my custom url for laravel storage?
(What about this url: `images.site.com/tamplate.png`)

Comment: Did you follow this? https://medium.com/@aleksander.tabor/custom-url-in-laravel-storage-8392a32ac955

Comment: Thanks @fuddin, It's worked! and what about subdomains like `images.site.com/tamplate.png`